# How to pipe two seperate outputs into a single program's input without a buffer

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, stdin, unbuffered

I have an executable python script, `process-data.py` that reads live input through stdin and processes it in real time. I want to feed it two types of data: images, and raw text. both are generated from other python scripts.

processing text works when using `unbuffer` and a pipe like so:

`unbuffer ./text-output.py | ./process-data.py`

doing the same for the image data also works

`unbuffer ./image-output.py | ./process-data.py`

How would I run both `image-output.py` and `text-output.py` at the same time and process the data without a delay from a buffer? I have tried using cat, but it doesn't work in real time (both "output" scripts generate their data over time and do so indefinitely)

Comment: How will the receiving script know what is what on its input channel? How can it distinguish images from text when they are all interleaved?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, the program is capable of discerning the difference. It knows the syntax of the text data and the image-output prefixes images with a special character sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use named pipes:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
./text-output.py > /tmp/pipe &
./image-output.py > /tmp/pipe &
./process-data.py < /tmp/pipe
rm /tmp/pipe
```

But remember, that pipes (named and unnamed) still use buffers inside.

Comment: Is there a way to use unbuffer with named pipes? The real time aspect is especially important.